# How can I avoid absolute positionned hidden element to overlap others elements when revealed?

Tags: css

I' m looking for a css rule regarding **absolute positionned elements**.

**This is my scenario :**

I have 6 images, each one must reveal a hidden div on click.

**My questions are the following :**

1-How to make the hidden div in absolute position push the elements below instead of overlaping them?

2-How to make the arrow above the hidden div always centered on the image above?

```js
$('.img').on('click', function() {

    $('.reveal').removeClass('slideDown');
    $(this).next().addClass('slideDown');
})
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.reveal').removeClass('slideDown');
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 540px) {
    .flex-container {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-container {
        max-width: 768px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .flex-container {
        max-width: 992px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .flex-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}

.flex-row {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.flex-col-xs-4,
.flex-col-sm-4,
.flex-col-md-4,
.flex-col-lg-4 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 540px) {
    .flex-col-xs-4 {
        max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
        width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .flex-col-sm-4 {
        max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
        width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .flex-col-md-4 {
        max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
        width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .flex-col-lg-4 {
        max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
        width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video-wrapper {}

.close {
    color: #ffffff!important;
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.reveal-container {
    position: relative;
}

.reveal-video-wrapper {
    max-width: 540px;
    width: 100%;
}

.reveal {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px;
}

.reveal::before {
    top: 6px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #ddd;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 25%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
}

.reveal.slideDown {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 677px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.reveal-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-row">

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DrBy7MyiqJU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos flex-col-md-4">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <div class="reveal-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YkkezwcBZLQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos flex-col-md-4">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <div class="reveal-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fR2q_Xe7kqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos flex-col-md-4">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <div class="reveal-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos flex-col-md-4">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <div class="reveal-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iaAgm4lO3tw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infos flex-col-md-4">
                            <h3>Title</h3>
                            <div class="reveal-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-col-md-4"><img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                <div class="reveal">
                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <a class="close">&times;</a>
                    <div class="reveal-content">

                        <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-md-8">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fR2q_Xe7kqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</article>
```

Comment: It seems like you don't want it to be absolutely positionned. If I understand correctly I would just switch .reveal to be relative and adjust CSS so it displays as you want.

Comment: Okay got it, the trick is to update your selected item's height. You need to apply your "slideDown" class to the parent ".flex-col-md-4". And in your CSS define the height of the selected item to be regular height + absolute element height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried your code, finaly it partially work and the key is the margin-bottom.

Your answer solve the problem partially, as it relies on fixed margin and height of elements. From your example, if I make the iframe responsive (and not with fixed width and height) I'll have to change the margin bottom manually (media queries) at every window resize event, and every break points.

I finaly found a solution, with jquery calculating the height and margin bottom of html blocks. This way, It is fully responsive. For some reason, here in the S.O editor, the div overlaps (whatever the height of 'var padding') but in browser it is working !!

Here is the code

```js
$('.open').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().next().addClass('active');
})  
$('.close').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
})
   
$('.reveal-img').on('click',function(){  
  var padding = 40;
  $('.block').removeClass('slideDown');
  $('.block').css('margin-bottom','0');
  $('.reveal').css('height','0');
  $(this).parent().addClass('slideDown');
  
  $(this).parent().css({'margin-bottom': $(".reveal-content").height() + padding + 'px'});
  $(this).next().css({ "height": $('.reveal-content').height() + padding + 'px'});
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.slideDown').offset().top
   }, 500);
 })
 
$('.close').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('slideDown');
  $(this).parent().parent().css('margin-bottom','0px');
  $(this).parent().css('height','0');
})
```

```css
/* ========================================================================== FLEX BOX CUTSOM GRID ========================================================================== */
 .flex-container {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0 1em;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-container {
         max-width: 540px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-container {
         max-width: 768px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-container {
         max-width: 992px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-container {
         max-width: 1200px;
    }
}
 .flex-row {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin-bottom: 1em;
}
 .flex-col-xs-12, .flex-col-sm-12, .flex-col-md-12, .flex-col-lg-12 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-12 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-12 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-12 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-12 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (12 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-11, .flex-col-sm-11, .flex-col-md-11, .flex-col-lg-11 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-11 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-11 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-11 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-11 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (11 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-10, .flex-col-sm-10, .flex-col-md-10, .flex-col-lg-10 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-10 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-10 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-10 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-10 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (10 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-9, .flex-col-sm-9, .flex-col-md-9, .flex-col-lg-9 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-9 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-9 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-9 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-9 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (9 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-8, .flex-col-sm-8, .flex-col-md-8, .flex-col-lg-8 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-8 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-8 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-8 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-8 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (8 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-7, .flex-col-sm-7, .flex-col-md-7, .flex-col-lg-7 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-7 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-7 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-7 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-7 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (7 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-6, .flex-col-sm-6, .flex-col-md-6, .flex-col-lg-6 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-6 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-6 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-6 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-6 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (6 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-5, .flex-col-sm-5, .flex-col-md-5, .flex-col-lg-5 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-5 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-5 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-5 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-5 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (5 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-4, .flex-col-sm-4, .flex-col-md-4, .flex-col-lg-4 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-4 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-4 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-4 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-4 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (4 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-3, .flex-col-sm-3, .flex-col-md-3, .flex-col-lg-3 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-3 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-3 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-3 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-3 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (3 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-2, .flex-col-sm-2, .flex-col-md-2, .flex-col-lg-2 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-2 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-2 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-2 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-2 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (2 / 12));
    }
}
 .flex-col-xs-1, .flex-col-sm-1, .flex-col-md-1, .flex-col-lg-1 {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (min-width: 540px) {
     .flex-col-xs-1 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .flex-col-sm-1 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .flex-col-md-1 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .flex-col-lg-1 {
         max-width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
         width: calc(100% * (1 / 12));
    }
}
/*******************************************/
 .video-container {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .video-container iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .video-wrapper {
}
 .close {
     color: #ffffff !important;
     float: right;
     font-size: 60px;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-decoration: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 30px;
     right: 30px;
     z-index: 999;
}
 .close:hover, .close:focus {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
}
/*****************************/
/* cc grid*/
/****************************/
 .block{
     margin-bottom:0;
     transition: margin .5s ease-in;
}
 .block .close {
     top: 15px;
     right: 15px;
}
 .block.slideDown{
     margin-bottom: 380px;
}
 .reveal-container{
     position:relative;
}
 .reveal-video-wrapper{
     width:100%;
}
 .reveal-video-wrapper{
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
     transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
 .reveal{
     visibility:hidden;
     opacity:0;
     position: absolute;
     background: #ddd;
     top: auto;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 20px;
     text-align: left;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: height .3s ease-in;
     padding-top:35px 
}
 .reveal-content{
     display:flex;
     justify-content:flex-start;
     align-items:center;
     flex-wrap:wrap 
}
 .reveal-img{
     position:relative 
}
.reveal-img img{
  max-width:100%
  }
 .slideDown .reveal-video-wrapper{
     visibility:visible;
     opacity:1;
}
 .slideDown .reveal{
     visibility:visible;
     opacity:1;
     height: auto;
     overflow: visible;
}
 .slideDown .reveal-img::after {
     bottom:-21px;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-right: 16px solid transparent;
     border-left: 16px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 20px solid #ddd;
     content: " ";
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
     border-width: 15px;
     left:50%;
     margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
   <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-row">
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DrBy7MyiqJU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YkkezwcBZLQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fR2q_Xe7kqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-row">
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iaAgm4lO3tw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6  flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="flex-col-sm-4 block">
            <div class="reveal-img">
               <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1578405302740-01f514c1ec64?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
               <!-- Modal content -->
               <a class="close">&times;</a>
               <div class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="reveal-video-wrapper flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-8">
                     <div class="video-container">
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fR2q_Xe7kqA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="infos flex-col-lg-6 flex-col-sm-4">
                     <h3>Title</h3>
                     <div class="reveal-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the quick solution to keep an absolutely positionned overlay is to affect the height of the selected item row.

Your HTML and CSS are kind of broken and overly complicated. I've made a simplified example using a margin animation to fix your issue. You could of course adjust animations using delays to make transitions smoother.

```js
function close() {
    $('.row').removeClass('is-expanded')
        .find('li[aria-expanded="true"]').attr('aria-expanded', false);
}

$('input[type="image"]').on('click', function() {

    close();
    $(this).parent().attr('aria-expanded', true)
        .parents('.row').addClass('is-expanded');
});

$('.close').on('click', close);
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.row li {
    width: 23%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: margin .5s ease-in;
}


input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

article {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    transition: height .5s ease-in;
    background: grey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

article > button {
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    outline: 0;
}

article iframe {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}

li[aria-expanded="true"] {
    margin-bottom: 180px;
}

li[aria-expanded="true"] article {
   height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="row">
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum A</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum B</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum C</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum D</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="row">
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum E</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum F</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum G</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476480862126-209bfaa8edc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
                <article>
                    <button class="close">X</button>
                    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rQhHkr-1qGc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum H</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If the row only contains a single element you can simply move your slideDown class to $(this).parent(). Then in your CSS you increase the height of the select row. To be equal to row height + overlay height (your overlay would thus be positioned at bottom 0 relativerly to the row).

If your row contains multiple entries, you can use a second class to only change the row's height.

Comment: I'll try to make a working snippet and edit the answer.

Comment: Actually everything in your snippet is broken so its hard to display what you expect I'll make a simplified version you can extrapolate from

Comment: Yes thank you very much !! I answered to you and didn't see you edited your answer with code. Thanks a lot, I'll try your version which as you say looks much more simple and thus more efficient !!